# Drupal cache not here?

Tags: caching, performance

I'm in charge of a website that have an huge amount of queries all the time, so we activated drupal cache (in performance). It was great, for all guests the page was very fast to load (not so fast for logged in users).

Right now, I'm migrating the server to a new one, I managed to update everything, and I use HHVM, and it's really great, the page load very fast actually. But I noticed on the new server, that the page for guests and logged in users takes the same time to load, and on the old server, I have a "cache" directory in the main folder, not on the new server.
(to migrate, I installed a new drupal, and I moved the module directory, the themes one, and the db).

And I made a test with siege, on the old server, it would return 301 sometimes, while it always return 200 on the new server.

So basically, everything works fine, really fast compare to the old server, except I think the drupal cache doesn't work :(

Comment: Sounds like you're using the boost module (cache dir); check your .htaccess file.

Comment: Ah, we used boost module before but not anymore (stupid reason but well, not my decision), so that's why. I will check apache for the cache then.

Thx! :)